# What would you call the person tending to the children in a preschool?

Tags: word-request

Here, that person is always a lady whose job involves taking care of the kids, for example,  when they need to go to the bathroom. She may be assigned other duties as well, such as keeping the preschool's bathrooms clean. I know words like *babysitter*, *childminder*, *nurse* and *nanny*, but I don't know if any of them would work for this specific situation.

Comment: In the UK it would be a nursery nurse, I strongly suspect it is different in the US.

Answer (score 3):

In the US, at least, the general *class* of professionals who take care of children are termed **Child Care Workers**.  Within this group there are many different titles, depending on the job: *aide, attendant, assistant, helper, coordinator, staff*, or just *worker*, often specialized to different levels of care, such as *daycare, baby care, preschool*, and so on.

> Here at Children's Academy, in addition to our teachers we have a number of **daycare staff** to help look after the kids.

[List of Job Titles - Early childhood educators and assistants (Canada)](https://www.jobbank.gc.ca/job_titles-eng.do;jsessionid=16AA220225909A9231861572403F738A.imnav4?area=9219&lang=eng&noc=4214&backurl=%2Freport-eng.do%3Farea%3D9219%26lang%3Deng%26noc%3D4214)